# Cannot assume lookup role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy an AWS CDK pipeline from Account A (deployments account) to Account B (workload account). As part of my CDK code I am performing a lookup of a VPC ID:

```
      var lambdaVpc = Vpc.FromLookup(this, "VPC", new VpcLookupOptions{ 
        VpcId = Vpc.id
      });
```

However, when my Pipeline runs I get the following error:

```
Could not assume role in target account using current credentials (which are for account ${DeploymentAccount}) 
User: arn:aws:sts::${DeploymentAccount}:assumed-role/te-cdk-pipeline-mis-servi-tecdkpipelinemisservicej-UPT0J1RO1RFR/AWSCodeBuild-7bcbd3a0-8159-454b-a886-18f8dd1df58c is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: 
arn:aws:iam::${WorkloadAccount}:role/cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-${WorkloadAccount}-ap-southeast-2 . 
Please make sure that this role exists in the account. If it doesn't exist, (re)-bootstrap the environment with the right '--trust', using the latest version of the CDK CLI.
```

My Workload Account role has the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${WorkloadAccount}:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${DeploymentAccount}:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

As far as I can tell, this should allow the Deployment Account to assume and use this role. All of these Roles/Permissions were created by CDK/the bootstrapping process.

I have tried deleting my pipeline and redeploying (so that CDK recreates all the IAM Roles/Policies) but no luck so far.

Has anyone come across this?

Comment: What is `${WorkloadAccount}` and `${DeploymentAccount}`?

Comment: Placeholders for the account ID's which I did not want to include.

Comment: Are you using CDK pipelines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended practice is to synth the app once on a local machine with the necessary permissions to do the lookup, then commit `cdk.context.json` to git, which will make the pipeline use the cached values and not need to perform any lookups.

What this achieves is the best practice of making your CDK code deterministic - it should always synth to the same template, and making sure you only do the network call once achieves this.